# Docker command permission denied in pipeline but works correct in SSH sesion

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

Our pipeline executes commands:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account jenkins@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file /var/lib/jenkins/gkeys/keyfile.json
docker pull gcr.io/myproject/myimage.v15
```

We receive the error from docker pull:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fmyproject%2Fmyimage&tag=v15: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

When we run the same commands in SSH session on the Jenkins server with user jenkins both of them work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Jenkins service solved the problem